# Nuxt 3 and useFetch with Laravel Sanctum: 419 CSRF Token Mismatch

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

have spent an hour to integrate nuxt 3 with laravel sanctum but still getting `419: CSRF Token Mismatch` on the laravel side

Nuxt served at http://localhost:3000/:

```js
export const useCustomFetch = (url, opts) => {
  
    return useFetch(url, { 
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
        credentials: 'include',
        ...opts 
    })
}

export const csrfToken = async () => {
    await useCustomFetch('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
}

 await csrfToken()

    const { data, error } = await useCustomFetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData.value)
    })
```

Laravel served at http://localhost:8000/

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
```

anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved it.

```js
export const useCustomFetch = (url, opts) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    const xsrfToken = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN')
    let headers = {
        accept: 'application/json',
        ...opts?.headers,
    }
    if (xsrfToken && xsrfToken.value !== null) {
        headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = xsrfToken;
    }
    if (process.server) {
        headers = {
            ...headers,
            ...useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
            referer: config.public.baseURL
        }
    }
    return useFetch(url, {
        baseURL: config.public.apiBaseUrl,
        headers,
        credentials: 'include',
        ...opts,
    })
}
```